# Как заставить пользователя заново авторизироваться?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

После того как задаю пользователю новую роль нужно как-то выбросить его из системы и заставить заново перезайти. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать.

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ChangeUserRole(string id, string role)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            var userRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
            await UserManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(id, userRoles.ToArray());
            await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(id, role);
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }
        catch
        {
            return Json(new {success = false});
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Должна быть настроена инвалидация кук в Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = 
            DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Включение проверки валидности security stamp когда пользователь пытается авторизоваться.
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator
                  .OnValidateIdentity<UserManager, User>(
                      validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                      regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });    
    }
```

А потом в своем методе вызвать обновление security stamp.

```
await userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id);
```

Таким образом пользователю придется авторизоваться заново при заходе на сайт.